# Replace ParseFloat(.ToFixed()) with .toLocaleString() for precision money

Tags: javascript

As many of you know, when adding decimal(float) values in javascript, you wind up with interesting results sometimes. Example:

```
0.1 + 0.2         ->  0.30000000000000004
```

To fix that I implemented `.ParseFloat()` with `.toFixed()` like so many SO questions offer as answers:

```
parseFloat((profitTotal - taxesTotal).toFixed(10))
```

Then to convert it to money I wound up with this from another SO answer:

```
(parseFloat((profitTotal - taxesTotal).toFixed(10))).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD',}))
```

However, it dawned on me that I could probably just eliminate the `ParseFloat` and `toFixed` and do the following:

```
(profitTotal - taxesTotal).toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD',})
```

...and wind up with the correct value most of the time. This appears to work in every case I've tested so far (which is not a whole lot). I don't think I'll ever wind up with too many decimal places. However, I'm worried I might end up a few cents plus or minus in some cases?

Anyone know if my last conversion works precisely when adding/subtracting money?

Comment: it's better to do math on cents than dollars (no float madness). you can then divide by 100 before displaying to the user.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the insight. Currently, I'm dealing with a huge ledger type situation where I'd have to convert to cents first which, with all these other conversions, may be the best way to go. On a separate thought, I think my example is not the greatest either as it implies only the final value. I have `FloatParse...` all over the place to keep my sanity as well as build an array of individual chart values.